# Reference request. The adjunction $\hom_{CDGA}(\Omega^\bullet(A),B^\bullet)\cong\hom_{CA}(A,B^0)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

We have the adjunction
$$\hom_{CDGA}(\Omega^\bullet(A),B^\bullet)\cong\hom_{CA}(A,B^0)$$
where $CDGA$ is the category of commutative diffferential graded algebras and $CA$ is the category of commutative algebras. $\Omega^\bullet(A)$ stands for algebraic de-Rham complex.

I read about it in [this Qiaochu Yuan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464553/universal-property-of-de-rham-differential). I verified this, but still some reference would be useful.